# SQL for Calclate sum of Sales At particular time every day

Tags: sql, sql-server

Order Table.Reprpesents Order Date and Created is time at which record was inserted

```
Price   OrderDate   Created
240.00  2021-12-26  2021-12-26 05:17:38.710
13.00   2021-12-26  2021-12-26 04:17:28.810
4.00    2021-12-26  2021-12-26 03:07:50.507
7.00    2021-12-26  2021-12-26 02:07:50.507
119.00  2021-12-26  2021-12-26 01:07:50.507


16      2021-12-25  2021-12-26 23:56:06.810
108.00  2021-12-25  2021-12-26 12:56:02.140
162.00  2021-12-25  2021-12-26 09:50:54.667
40.00   2021-12-25  2021-12-26 05:17:38.710
23.00   2021-12-25  2021-12-26 04:17:28.810
40.00   2021-12-25  2021-12-26 03:07:50.507
7.00    2021-12-25  2021-12-26 02:07:50.507
100.00  2021-12-25  2021-12-26 01:07:50.507
```

The laltest record in this table is at(Created value) - 05:17:38.710

```
Select Max(Created) From dbo.TenantOrder -
```

> Output - 2021-12-26 05:17:38.710

At this time on 26th i.e. today's date the sales was

```
Select SUM(Price) From dbo.TenantOrder Where OrderDate = (Select Max(OrderDate) From dbo.TenantOrder)
```

At the same time I want to know the sales on 25th

```
Select SUM(Price) From dbo.TenantOrder Where OrderDate = (Select (Max(OrderDate) -1) From dbo.TenantOrder) and Created <= (Select Max(Created) -1 From dbo.TenantOrder)
```

I want this kind of record for every day i.e. group by order date and at the max created time.
So like at 5PM what was the sales every day

Comment: So you want results from the whole table grouped for every day, but only where the time of day is less than the time of day of the latest row `05:17:38.710`? Are your using MySQL or SQL Server, please correct your tags

Comment: Corrected tag.  Yes everyday at certain time what was sale. So that I can analyse how behind or forward we are from last day or any day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code:

```
select sum(Price) as SuumPrice
from dbo.TenantOrder
group by OrderDate
```

and for particular time:

```
select sum(price) as SuumPrice
from (
    select *
    from dbo.TenantOrder
    where convert(varchar(5),Created ,108) = N'12:10'
) as Dt
group by Dt.OrderDate
```

Comment: At particular time everyday I want.

Comment: Do you want the last order of per  day? @Manjay_TBAG

Comment: why is  the hard coded value.

Comment: which place? what you mean?

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface can you tell me any new way. I want to Improve my SQL Server  performance skill. Many thanks.

Comment: If you want to check a time you can use `CAST(... AS time)` or if you have a specific time *and* date you should use datetime start and end range with `>= AND <`

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. if it is possible please tell me how I can change  `where CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),Created ,108) = N'12:10' ` to better way.

Comment: @Charlieface thank. I saw your new post. Thanks very much. I will definitely consider this next time to improve the efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want grouped totals for every day, but only up to the time which marks the same time as the latest row in the table.

In SQL Server you can use the following

```
DECLARE @time time = (
    SELECT TOP (1)
      CAST(o.OrderDate AS time)
    FROM dbo.TenantOrder o
    ORDER BY o.OrderDate DESC);

SELECT
  date = CAST(o.OrderDate AS date),
  total = SUM(o.price)
FROM TenantOrder o
WHERE CAST(o.OrderDate AS time) <= @time
GROUP BY
  CAST(o.OrderDate AS date);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ae89421616e08346d322ce5ff5e75f00)

Comment: This is not giving expected result, Please see I have two datetime column, my OrderDate hold only Dates but Created hold time field also Created is always in utc but orderdate can be any time zone.  I tried to change in declare Created in place of order date but then also I am not getting expected result.  For one OrderDate it is not necessary that Created will have same date as created in UTC but order date can be anything

Comment: I'm unsure then what you want. Expected output would help immensely. Please edit your question and put in expected output